# nginx and cloudlfare ip confusion?

Tags: linux, nginx, bandwidth, rate-limiting, cloudflare

I am using the below config in `http` block of my `nginx.conf` to get real ip while using Cloudflare acceleration service:

```
    ## Cloudflare settings to get Real IP's
    set_real_ip_from   204.93.240.0/24;
    set_real_ip_from   204.93.177.0/24;
    set_real_ip_from   199.27.128.0/21;
    set_real_ip_from   173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from   108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from   190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   188.114.96.0/20;   
    set_real_ip_from   197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   198.41.128.0/17;
    set_real_ip_from   162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from   2400:cb00::/32;
    set_real_ip_from   2606:4700::/32;
    set_real_ip_from   2803:f800::/32;
    set_real_ip_from   2405:b500::/32;
    set_real_ip_from   2405:8100::/32;
    real_ip_header     CF-Connecting-IP;
```

I am also using nginx rate limiting feature defined below the above config as:

```
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=two:30m;
```

Which is being enforced by `limit_conn two 16;` directive in php `location` block inside the 'default' file at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

My question is, is this correct and will it NOT throttle and block Cloudflare IP's?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own experience (I also use Nginx with CloudFlare) and a quote from the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) I can tell that it is indeed correct and CloudFlare IPs won't be throttled or blocked.

> The ngx_http_realip_module module is used to change the client address